# How to make a 3D plot in matplotlib from data z=f(x,y) read from file

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, mplot3d

I need to create a 3D plot in matplotlib. I am reading Z values from a text file formated as 1D array. This data represents value for every point on a 50x50 square. So first 50 values are for points (0,0),(1,0)..(49,0), next 50 are for (0,1),(1,1) and so on. So far i have written the following code:

```py
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np

    fp=open(path,"r")
    a=fp.read()
    buffer=""
    data=[]
    for i in a:
        if i != ' ':
            buffer=buffer+i
        else:
            data.append(float(buffer))
            buffer=""
    fp.close()


    values=data[50*50:50*50*2]

    x=np.linspace(0,50,50)
    y=np.linspace(0,50,50)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, values)

    plt.show()
```

But of course it is not working. I searched the Internet for some clues but without any success. Can someone show me how I should done it? I would be more than grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you forgot to import Axes3D: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Second, you code has strange meaningless line: `values[50*50*nb:50*50*(nb+1)]` and indentation is wrong in your code.

Third, to plot regularly gridded data you do not need plot_trisurf, use plot_surface:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x=np.linspace(0,50,50)
y=np.linspace(0,50,50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
values = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Look for examples: http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html

Comment: Thanks for response. I edited the source code so the values is now ok.I must have deleted too much when editing. The problem is that I dont know how to format my data so it could be passed to plot_surface. In this examaple and in any other I have looked it was just generated based on function (np.sqrt here).

Comment: It does not matter how data (Z) is generated, you data just has to have the same shape as X and Y arrays. X, Y for `plot_surface` have to be a mesh grids (2D array of the same size).

Comment: Okay i have formated my data as 2D array and it worked :D. Thank you.